# How to take xpath of Going to field in https://www.expedia.com/ in flights tab using python with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am able to send keys to "Going to" field it is working, but not able to select from result. It is working in "Leaving from" field, please someone help me with "Going to" field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGoED.png)

```html
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from  selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[href='?pwaLob=wizard-flight-pwa'] span").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='Leaving from']").click()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,50)
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"location-field-leg1-origin")))
driver.find_element(By.ID,"location-field-leg1-origin").send_keys("Leaving from San Francisco (SFO - San Francisco Intl.)")
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='uitk-typeahead-button-label truncate']/span")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='uitk-typeahead-button-label truncate']/span").click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='Going to']").click()
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"location-field-leg1-destination")))
driver.find_element(By.ID,"location-field-leg1-destination").send_keys("Flying to New York, NY (JFK-John F. Kennedy Intl.)")
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='uitk-typeahead-button-label truncate']/span")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='uitk-typeahead-button-label truncate']/span").click()
```

Comment: provide the full code you are working on

Comment: I have attached my code now. Please take a look